# MySQL - select date for corrsponding weekday previous year

Tags: mysql, date, weekday

I have a table with dates and sales revenue for each date (see example below). I would like to compare the revenue for a given date to the same day previous year.

What complicates it all is that I want to compare sales on weekdays, not dates.

For example, I want to compare `2017-11-14` (a tuesday) to `2016-11-15` (a tuesday).

Another example is leap days, `2016-02-29` (a monday) should be compared to `2015-03-02` (a monday).

Is there a way to find the date for the corrsponding weekday previous year using MySQL?

```
+--------------+--------------+
| log_date     | revenue      |
+--------------+--------------+
| ...          | ...          |
+--------------+--------------+
| 2017-10-01   | 1000         |
+--------------+--------------+
| 2017-10-02   | 3000         |
+--------------+--------------+
| 2017-10-03   | 1500         |
+--------------+--------------+
| ...          | ...          |
+--------------+--------------+
```

### I came up with this solution (maybe not so elegant, but it works):

```
SET @this_years_date = '2017-03-31';
SET @last_years_date = DATE(DATE_SUB(@this_years_date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) + INTERVAL 
    IF (
        WEEKDAY(@this_years_date) != WEEKDAY(
            DATE(DATE_SUB(@this_years_date,INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
        ), 2, 1
    )
DAY;

SELECT revenue FROM table WHERE log_date = @last_years_date;
```

Comment: What do you mean by compare? You want to have a query that puts them side by side ?

Comment: @NicolaPedretti The "compare" part is not really the issue. I would like to find the date for the corrsponding weekday last year. To then query the table and put the numbers side by side is easy :-)

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was wrong. You should post your solution as an answer and accept it.