# MYSQL Comparing previous year by same week day

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, pivot

I have a series of sales transactions. I want to create a MySql query that will group the sales transactions by date but also have a column displaying the previous year's sales on the closest weekday.

I know I can use DATE_ADD to get the correct date. For instance the formula below will give me the date I want in relation to March 1, 2020:

```
DATE_ADD('2020-03-01', INTERVAL -52 WEEK)
```

The above returns March 3, 2019. But I don't know how to turn data like this:

```
+-----------+---------+
|Date       | Sales   |
|-----------+---------+
|2020-03-01 | 45.00   |
|2020-03-01 | 1.23    |
|2020-03-01 | 30.00   |
|2020-03-01 | 5.75    |
|2020-03-01 | 25.63   |
|2020-02-29 | 85.85   |
|2020-02-29 | 26.23   |
|2020-02-29 | 56.85   |
|2020-02-29 | 8.96    |
|2020-02-29 | 89.48   |
.
.
.
.
|2019-03-03 | 3.50    |
|2019-03-03 | 76.89   | 
|2019-03-03 | 1003.50 |
|2019-03-03 | 1.34    |
|2019-03-02 | 6.58    |
|2019-03-02 | 90.48   | 
|2019-03-02 | 32.12   |
|2019-03-02 | 45.89   |
|2019-03-02 | 353.21  |
|2019-03-02 | 3.71    | 
|2019-03-02 | 22.22   |
|2019-03-02 | 353.65  |
.
.
.
.
+-----------+---------+
```

Into a table like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|Date       | Curr Sales   | Last Yr Sales|
|-----------+--------------+--------------+
|2020-03-01 | 107.61       | 1085.23      |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
|2020-02-29 | 267.37       | 907.86       |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+
.
.
.
```

The data contains sales for almost every day of the year going back to 2015, it's not just for March 1 2020. So the returned table would have mutiple rows of dates

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: The problem is that there are more days this year than last year.  How should that be handled? Either one column will have  blank value or the other column will have duplicate data. Do you want  May 1st to match May 1st of last year or 52 weeks ago?

Comment: The leap year is not an issue because I am not trying to match the dates of the year, I am matching the week day that is closest to 365 days previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.date, t1.Sales as 'Curr Sales', t2.sales as 'Last Yr Sales'
from(
    SELECT Date, Sum(Sales) as sales
    from table1 
    group by date
) t1
left join(
    SELECT Date, Sum(Sales) as sales
    from table1 
    group by date
) t2
on DATE_SUB(t1.date, INTERVAL 52 WEEK) = t2.date
where t1.date >= '2020-01-01'
order by t1.date desc
```

Comment: This solution seems to work thanks! Not sure why the following line is needed though: ``` where t1.date >= '2020-01-01'```

Comment: What if I wan to add an additional column for 2 years before? It doesn't seem possible to just add another duplicated join with incremented numbers.

Comment: I figured out how to add additional years. The on clauses have to be in between every join clause and it works.

Comment: @user3511512 did you figure it your first question about the date in the where clause?

Answer (score 0):

One option is conditional aggregation:

```
select
    concat(date_format(current_date, '%Y'), '-', date_format(date, '%m-%d')) date,
    sum(case when date > current_date - interval 1 year then sales end) current_year_sales,
    sum(case when date <= current_date - interval 1 year then sales end) last_year_sales
from mytable
where date > current_date - interval 2 year
group by date_format(date, '%m-%d')
order by date_format(date, '%m-%d')
```

This gives you the daily sales for the last 365 days, along with the corresponding sales on the same day on the previous year.

Answer (score 0):

This will compare all dates this year with last year revenue, cpompared to the week day

I used the algorithm form this [MySQL - select date for corrsponding weekday previous year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576489/mysql-select-date-for-corrsponding-weekday-previous-year)

> ```
> SELECT
> `Date`
> ,ROUND(SUM(`Sales`),2) SUmthisyear
> ,(SELECT ROUND(SUM(IF(`Date` = DATE(DATE_SUB(t1.`Date`, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) + INTERVAL 
>     IF (
>         WEEKDAY(t1.`Date`) != WEEKDAY(
>             DATE(DATE_SUB(t1.`Date`,INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
>         ), 2, 1
>     ) DAY,`Sales`,0) ),2)
>  
>  FROM table1) SUmpreviousyear
> FROM table1 t1
> WHERE YEAR(`Date`) = YEAR(NOW())
> GROUP  BY `Date`
> ORDER BY `Date`
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `Date` DATE,
>   `Sales` FLOAT
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`Date`, `Sales`)
> VALUES
>   ('2020-03-01', '45.00'),
>   ('2020-03-01', '1.23'),
>   ('2020-03-01', '30.00'),
>   ('2020-03-01', '5.75'),
>   ('2020-03-01', '25.63'),
>   ('2020-02-29', '85.85'),
>   ('2020-02-29', '26.23'),
>   ('2020-02-29', '56.85'),
>   ('2020-02-29', '8.96'),
>   ('2020-02-29', '89.48'),
>   ('2019-03-03', '3.50'),
>   ('2019-03-03', '76.89'),
>   ('2019-03-03', '1003.50'),
>   ('2019-03-03', '1.34'),
>   ('2019-03-02', '6.58'),
>   ('2019-03-02', '90.48'),
>   ('2019-03-02', '32.12'),
>   ('2019-03-02', '45.89'),
>   ('2019-03-02', '353.21'),
>   ('2019-03-02', '3.71'),
>   ('2019-03-02', '22.22'),
>   ('2019-03-02', '353.65');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> `Date`
> ,ROUND(SUM(`Sales`),2) SUmthisyear
> ,(SELECT ROUND(SUM(IF(`Date` = DATE(DATE_SUB(t1.`Date`, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) + INTERVAL 
>     IF (
>         WEEKDAY(t1.`Date`) != WEEKDAY(
>             DATE(DATE_SUB(t1.`Date`,INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
>         ), 2, 1
>     ) DAY,`Sales`,0) ),2)
>  
>  FROM table1) SUmpreviousyear
> FROM table1 t1
> WHERE YEAR(`Date`) = YEAR(NOW())
> GROUP  BY `Date`
> ORDER BY `Date`
> ```
>
> ```
> Date       | SUmthisyear | SUmpreviousyear
> :--------- | ----------: | --------------:
> 2020-02-29 |      267.37 |          907.86
> 2020-03-01 |      107.61 |         1085.23
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=83e664357dff777bfeefaa3c0ce75414)*